# Requirement : Open Source API providing properties of engineering materials

Tags: mechanical-engineering, materials, civil-engineering, material-science

We are a bunch of four in the ultimate year of the 'Bachelor of Engineering - Mechanical' degree. Our final year project is titled 'Computer-Aided Part-Code Generator for industrial parts'.

For the same, we've got a few open-source databases of engineering materials with various properties like https://mechanicalc.com/reference/engineering-materials. But we're looking for an Open Source API.

Regarding the project,

It has two sections :

Generate Part-Code for the selected item

Scan QR code/Paste Part-Code to know the properties

It's a web application that generates a PART-CODE (say, Random Unique Code) based on the inputs that are generally involved in the production side like the type of materials, alloys or composites, dimensions, etc., and it shows the other detailed material properties of the item chosen in a table (editable if modifications allowed). The PART-CODE, converted to QR code, can be sent to the materials-supplier side. All the properties can be get from the QR code itself.

As of now, we're focusing on Bus-body building industries.

The motive of the outcome of the project is that the QR code generated and used should minimize/eliminate the logistics troubles.

Any suggestions regarding the improvement of our project are welcome. Guide us with your knowledge in the field.

Thanking you, looking forward.

Comment: Welcome to Engineering! This seems like an interesting project, but the StackExchange format isn't a good fit for this sort of question, which is better suited to standard forums where discussions are welcome (there are many great ones online!). The StackExchange format is instead aimed at answering specific questions with a single objective answer. I'm therefore closing this question as too broad for our format, but you are more than welcome to ask any specific, objective (engineering-related) questions you may come up with during your project. Good luck!